`Error: conflict: User *** already exists` even when the user is not registered
When I try to change the password for my account, I get this error:
root@ip-172-26-***-***:/home/admin# su -c "/usr/sbin/ejabberdctl change_password pavlik 3.79.***.*** ***" ejabberd
{not_found,"unknown_user"}

And when I try to register that account:
root@ip-172-26-***-***:/home/admin# su -c "/usr/sbin/ejabberdctl register pavlik 3.79.***.*** ***" ejabberd
Error: conflict: User pavlik@3.79.***.*** already registered

Here's my config:
loglevel: info
log_rotate_count: 0
hosts:
    - "xmpp.pyt.pp.ua"
    - "3.79.***.***"
sql_type: pgsql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "***"

default_db: sql

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    
    request_handlers:
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
  -
    port: 3478
    ip: "::"
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true

  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

disable_sasl_mechanisms:
  - "digest-md5"
  - "X-OAUTH2"

auth_password_format: scram

acl:
  admin:
     user:
       - "admin"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: loopback
          - acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 200000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam: {}
  
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
    db_type: sql
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_pres_counter:
    count: 5
    interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: open
      
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_sic: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version: {}

What am I doing wrong?

It turns out that the problem was in the table permissions.
When I replaced the permissions of all tables in the ejabberd database with this command:
grant select, update, insert, delete on <table name> to ejabberd;

Everything worked as it should.

Great! I wonder if you can mark your own answer as the definitive answer, to mark this question as solved...
